# Edit related resource in react admin

Tags: react-admin, api-platform.com

I have a OneToOne relation between a Place and an Address resource; everything works fine with the Create :

```
<Create { ...props } title="Place > add">
    <TabbedForm>
        ...
        <FormTab label="Address">
            <TextInput source="address.streetAddress" label="Street Address" />
            <TextInput source="address.postalCode" label="Postal code" />
            ...
        </FormTab>
        ...
    </TabbedForm>
</Create>
```

When i submit, the Place is created as well as the related Address. But when i do the same with Edit, the Address fields are not populated :

```
<Edit { ...props } title="Place > edit">
    <TabbedForm>
        ...
        <FormTab label="Address">
            <TextInput source="address.streetAddress" label="Street Address" /> <- empty
            <TextInput source="address.postalCode" label="Postal code" /> <- empty
            ...
        </FormTab>
        ...
    </TabbedForm>
</Edit>
```

How to populate the fields with the related values ?

Note 1 : the Address is well retrieved by the api

Note 2 : the api will take care of the new values sent by the form

Note 3 : i am using api-platform and the hydra client for react admin, could it be related ?

Comment: if it is actual now, check browser console, what does api respond to client? is response code 200? try to do request in terminal by curl and check logs on server side